# machine learning and m-estimate

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a machine learning problem and have some outliers in my data and would like to smoothen them. I read something about using m-estimate to solve such problem. I have search exhaustively on both the Web and stackoverflow but could not find a good example. Can someone suggests some resources where I can read more about this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator There are plenty of references here

Comment: Saw that. I am looking for examples in the context of machine learning. m-estimate was mentioned at hight level [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919923/m-estimate-for-continuous-values) and it makes sense. But, I could not grasp the concept fully without seeing an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M-estimator originates from the work of Huber, if I remember well. He studied ways to make estimators robust. To measure robustness however, a very specific type of robustness was considered. It is called the "breakdown point", which is simple the percentage of outliers compared to the overall number of points that the method can cope with. One more outlier, and it breaks down.

Note, that this type of robustness is something quite different from robustness in computer vision. In computer vision outliers might not be many, but they might conspire (in the form of structured points) to break down the most robust estimators. In computer vision for that reason you will encounter the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) and [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) to perform robust estimations of lines.

Also, a type of M-estimator that is very resilient against outliers, is an M-estimator that bounds the value assigned to extreme outliers. These are so-called [redescending M-estimators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redescending_M-estimator). They are really robust, due to the fact that extreme outliers, called `gross outliers`, are assigned zero weight, or in other words just not taken into account in the regression at all.

If you want to know the influence of a single outlier, I challenge you to write a simple linear least squares octave program. Or if you think it's easier, a total least squares program (you can just do a singular value decomposition and `svd` is built-in).